# Is there a way to send audio from two different sources trough one peer (WebRTC)

Tags: javascript, webrtc, amazon-kinesis-video-streams

I'm trying to send the mic audio alongside with a audio file (two different tracks) using one stream. How can I properly do it using JS?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is a nice question, I've never tried this approach because i will face many troubles to consumer, the peer which receive this track with multi channel, you should provide a way to sync its stream or let him change the desired track.

But you can provide a solution with some sip server, such as Freeswitch, where you can receive multiple tracks and turn then into one so deliver to other, peer, looks a better approach.

Comment: And you have some reference for syncing the stream using both tracks?

Comment: Its a long way, but i think you can! you can start by access the official reference: 
https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Introduction later you can meet a very nice project whose use this approach, 

https://docs.bigbluebutton.org/

Problably your start point can be this magnificent project. Good luck

Comment: Dois brasileiros conversando em inglês,,, But thanks!

Comment: Yeah! i'm agreed with you :) Vai Corinthians!

Comment: I think you guys got it totally wrong, a stream is representative of a transport incoming or outgoing. You can attach as many tracks to this transport as you'd like. This is straight up off topic.